# Argument of Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | Date'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to convert the data am getting from the `dateRange` variable, but I'm getting an error: `Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'number | Date'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | Date'`.
What's wrong with my code?

//header file

import { useContextState } from '../context/context'

const Header = () => {
const { dateRange, setDateRange, setOpenDate, openDate } = useContextState()

```
return (
           <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(true)} className="cursor-pointer">
            {`${format(dateRange[0].startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")} To ${format(dateRange[0].endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")}`}
        </span>
                     
    </nav>
)
}

export default Header
// context.tsx file

import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';
import { Range } from "react-date-range";
import { format } from "date-fns";

export interface Range {
    startDate?: Date | undefined ;
    endDate?: Date | undefined;
    key?: string | undefined
}
interface IstateContext {
    openDate: boolean
    setOpenDate: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
    dateRange: Range[]
    setDateRange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Range[]>>
}

const initialState = {
    openDate: false,
    setOpenDate: () => false,
    dateRange: [{
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        key: "selection",
    }],
    setDateRange: () => void{}

}

const StateContext = createContext<IstateContext>(initialState)

interface Childern {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

export const ContextProvider: React.FC<Childern> = ({ children }) => {
    const [openDate, setOpenDate] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<Range[]>([
        {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(),
            key: "selection",
        },
    ])


    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{ dateRange, setDateRange, openDate, setOpenDate
        }}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}
export const useContextState = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where in your code that error is happening, but you're basically trying to pass a potentially `undefined` value into a function that only takes `Date | number`. If you check if your argument isn't `undefined`, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to pass `dateRange.0.startDate/endDate` to the `format` function however the values could be undefined and `format` does not accept undefined values.

Using type guards you can check against undefined values and handle that case.

```
const range = dateRange?.[0];
if (range?.startDate === undefined || range?.endDate === undefined) {
    return <span>Invalid range!</span>
}
return (
    <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(true)} className="cursor-pointer">
            {`${format(range.startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")} To ${format(range.endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")}`}
    </span>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Range'. You have imported from "react-date-range". And also you have made an interface that is unable to overite the property.

replace the third line with the code and confirm if it works. "added null check"
{`${format(dateRange[0]?.startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")} To ${format(dateRange[0]?.endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")}`}